# Passing a Parameter from .js file to controller

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to pass a parameter from my .js file to controller.

```
"fnCreatedRow" : function(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
            $(nRow).attr("row-id", aData["channelRole"]);
            $(nRow).hover(function(event) {
                var row = $(event.target.parentNode);
                row.addClass('row-selected');
            }, function(event) {
                var row = $(event.target.parentNode);
                row.removeClass('row-selected');
            });
            $(nRow).click(function(event) {
                var row = $(event.target.parentNode);
                document.location.href = "role-service-search.json?id=" + row.attr("row-id");
            });
        }
```

I need to pass the role to the controller code below. But when I debug, the value of role in controller is null. The code below has to work when i dont pass the role as well as when i pass the role through above script.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/role-service-search", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public void searchRoleService(@ModelAttribute("request") final PageableRoleServiceSearchRequest request, final String role,
                   final BindingResult result) {
    if (request.getInput() == null) {
        RoleServiceSearchRequest newReq= new RoleServiceSearchRequest();
        if(role!=null)
        {
            newReq.setChannelRole(role);
        }

        request.setInput(newReq);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to annotate method argument `role` with `@RequestParam` to tell the framework how to map the query parameter.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/role-service-search", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public void searchRoleService(
                   @ModelAttribute("request") final PageableRoleServiceSearchRequest request,
                   @RequestParam(name = "id", required = false) final String role,
                   final BindingResult result) {
    if (request.getInput() == null) {
        RoleServiceSearchRequest newReq= new RoleServiceSearchRequest();
        if(role!=null)
        {
            newReq.setChannelRole(role);
        }

        request.setInput(newReq);
    }
}
```

Since you call it `id` in your URL, you have to provide the name of role parameter as `id`. Otherwise, you can rename the parameter in your URL.

Comment: I edited my answer, using the annotation as follows: `@RequestParam(name = "id", required = false)` should work.